# Updating JSON structure based on id

Tags: javascript, json, api

I was trying to update the town name in the below-given JSON structure.

```
    "City":[
   {
      "Name":"Delhi",
      "id":"c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321bd",
      "Towns":[
         {
            "Name":"MG Colony",
            "conditionId":"60d1f5eb-0222-4a84-879b-6699b0cfc1a4",
            "cid":"c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321bd"
         },
         {
            "Name":"DLF Colony",
            "conditionId":"60d1f5eb-0222-4a84-879b-7749b0cfc1a4",
            "cid":"c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321bd"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Name":"Pune",
      "id":"c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321ax",
      "Towns":[
         {
            "Name":"Hadapsar",
            "conditionId":"60d1f5eb-0222-4a84-879b-6699b0cfc1x4",
            "cid":"c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321ax"
         },
         {
            "Name":"Magarpatta",
            "conditionId":"60d1f5eb-0222-4a84-879b-7749b0cfc1f4",
            "cid":"c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321bax"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I wanted to change the town name from **"Hapdasar"** to **"Viman Nagar"** if my **cid** matches that of Hadapsar Town

Output which I wanted was:

```
   "City":[
   {
      "Name":"Delhi",
      "id":"c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321bd",
      "Towns":[
         {
            "Name":"MG Colony",
            "conditionId":"60d1f5eb-0222-4a84-879b-6699b0cfc1a4",
            "cid":"c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321bd"
         },
         {
            "Name":"DLF Colony",
            "conditionId":"60d1f5eb-0222-4a84-879b-7749b0cfc1a4",
            "cid":"c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321bd"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Name":"Pune",
      "id":"c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321ax",
      "Towns":[
         {
            "Name":"Viman Nagar",
            "conditionId":"60d1f5eb-0222-4a84-879b-6699b0cfc1x4",
            "cid":"c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321ax"
         },
         {
            "Name":"Magarpatta",
            "conditionId":"60d1f5eb-0222-4a84-879b-7749b0cfc1f4",
            "cid":"c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321bax"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I was using js map to iterate but was confused about how to replicate the exact structure.

Comment: your data does not respect JSON syntax, it is just a **part of**  javascript objects

Comment: @MisterJojo I have updated the structure

Comment: This is not clear. what is  `my cid` ...

Comment: it was not worth it, it was enough just to write that they are JS objects and not JSON texts (which must be transformed into javascript objects in order to be processed by javascript code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `map` alone is not enough to solve your problem, since you have two nested arrays. Maybe you can consider the possibility to use `map`twice?
For example:

```
var cid = "c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321ax";
var newName = "Viman Nagar";
City = City.map(function(city) {
  city.towns = city.towns.map(function(town) {
    if (town.cid === cid)
      town.name = newName;
    return town;
  });
  return city;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Atribute your object for

```
let cities = [{
    "Name": "Delhi"
     ...
}]
```

and then you can map over it

```
let result = cities.map(city => city.Towns.map(town => {
    if (town.Name === "Hadapsar") {
        return {
            ...town,
            Name: "Viman Nagar"
        }
    } else return town
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as follows:

- Iterate over `cities`
- In every iteration, iterate over `Towns`. If current town's `cid` is equal to the one to change, update its `Name`

```js
const changeTownName = (cities = [], cid, name) =>
  cities.map(({ Towns = [], ...props }) => ({
    ...props,
    Towns: Towns.map(town => town.cid === cid 
      ? { ...town, Name: name } 
      : { ...town }
    )
  }));

const cities = [
  { Name: 'Delhi', id: 'c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321bd', Towns: [ { Name: "MG Colony", conditionId: '60d1f5eb-0222-4a84-879b-6699b0cfc1a4', cid: 'c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321bd' }, { Name: "DLF Colony", conditionId: '60d1f5eb-0222-4a84-879b-7749b0cfc1a4', cid: 'c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321bd' } ] },
  { Name: 'Pune', id: 'c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321ax', Towns: [ { Name: "Hadapsar", conditionId: '60d1f5eb-0222-4a84-879b-6699b0cfc1x4', cid: 'c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321ax' }, { Name: "Magarpatta", conditionId: '60d1f5eb-0222-4a84-879b-7749b0cfc1f4', cid: 'c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321bax' } ] }
];
console.log( changeTownName(cities, 'c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321ax', 'Viman Nagar') );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider city as cities this code can help you;

```
cities.forEach(city => {
    city.Towns = city.Towns.map(el => {
        if (el.Name === 'Hapdasar') {
            el.Name = 'Viman Nagar';
        }
        return el;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop for each city in your array, and each town in the city. If the cid matches the town's cid, then change it;

```
const myNewTownName = "Viman Nagar";
const cid = "c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321ax";
for(let i = 0; i < myObj.City.length; i++){
    const city = myObj.City[i];
    for(let j = 0; j < city.Towns.length; j++){
        const town = city.Towns[j];
        if(cid === town.cid){
            town.Name = myNewTownName;
        }
        city.town[j] = town;//Updates city with the updated town
    }
    myObj.City[i] = city; //Updates myObj with the updated city
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result can also be obtained using nested `.forEach` loops to parsing through the outer and inner arrays, with an `if` block to examine the cid for the target town.

```js
const data = {
"City":[
   {
      "Name":"Delhi",
      "id":"c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321bd",
      "Towns":[
         {
            "Name":"MG Colony",
            "conditionId":"60d1f5eb-0222-4a84-879b-6699b0cfc1a4",
            "cid":"c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321bd"
         },
         {
            "Name":"DLF Colony",
            "conditionId":"60d1f5eb-0222-4a84-879b-7749b0cfc1a4",
            "cid":"c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321bd"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Name":"Pune",
      "id":"c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321ax",
      "Towns":[
         {
            "Name":"Hadapsar",
            "conditionId":"60d1f5eb-0222-4a84-879b-6699b0cfc1x4",
            "cid":"c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321ax"
         },
         {
            "Name":"Magarpatta",
            "conditionId":"60d1f5eb-0222-4a84-879b-7749b0cfc1f4",
            "cid":"c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321bax"
         }
      ]
   }
]

} // end data;


const targetCid = "c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321ax"; // cid for Hadapsar;

const objArray = data.City;

objArray.forEach(element => {
  
  element.Towns.forEach(element => {  
  
    if (element.cid == targetCid) {
      element.Name = "Viman Nagar";
    } // end if;
  
  }); // next object in Towns array;

});  // next object in objArray;
  


document.getElementById('output').textContent = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
```

```css
#output {
 white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```